# Android App losing use permissions after reboot

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions

I have been working on a simple soundboard app and I am having a strange issue.
The app works fine when it is first installed and any time after that, its only once the device its installed on is rebooted that it begins to have issues.

Once the device is reboot the app appears to loose one of its

Specifically:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

Here is the stake trace I see:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.wochstudios.soundboard, PID: 10105
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{9f2b05a 10105:com.wochstudios.soundboard/u0a155} (pid=10105, uid=10155) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3361)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4709)
    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2611)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1440)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1063)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:921)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:848)
    at com.wochstudios.soundboard.Utils.SoundPlayer.getFileDescriptorFromUri(SoundPlayer.java:55)
    at com.wochstudios.soundboard.Utils.SoundPlayer.playSound(SoundPlayer.java:25)
    at com.wochstudios.soundboard.Controllers.SoundboardController.playSound(SoundboardController.java:26)
    at com.wochstudios.soundboard.DisplayFragments.SoundboardFragment$ListViewClickListener.onItemClick(SoundboardFragment.java:160)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
```

I have the min and target sdk set to 19, and I've been testing using a device with API 22.

I've been banging my head against the all trying to figure this out, but haven't had any luck yet.

I've tried listing the permission twice in the manifest, updating the apps version code and name, uninstalling the app completely and reinstalling, nothing has work so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `Uri` coming from? Are you persisting the `Uri` between uses of your app (let alone reboots)? If yes, that's your problem.

Comment: I am storing these Uris in an SQLite database. I am not seeeing this issue between uses of the app, closing it and opening app or returning to it from the background do not cause an issue. The issue only happens after I reboot the device.

Comment: @DMcP89 I know it's been quite long. But could you remember if you found  a solution to this? I'm having the same situation.

Comment: @Renjith see the answer below. If you are looking for an example of it here is the repo for the project I was working on with this - https://github.com/DMcP89/SoundBoard. I use the persistent permissions call here - https://github.com/DMcP89/SoundBoard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/wochstudios/InfiniteSoundboards/Fragments/AddSoundDialogFragment.java#L103

Fair warning though this is a very old project so not sure if it will work still.

Comment: @DMcP89 Thanks! I have sorted it out. Yes, I used persistent permissions. However, I wasn't releasing them after use. I think it caused a few weird scenarios and the app ended up complaining about the permission. It's all good now. Thanks for your help once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Uri` that you get from another app may be short-lived, in terms of how long you can access its contents. The best analogy is a URL to a file on a Web site — if that URL requires an authenticated session, the URL will work so long as the user's session is still alive, after which the URL will no longer work, forcing the user to log in again.

If you are using [the Storage Access Framework APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) on Android 4.4+ to get this `Uri`, you can try to take persistable `Uri` permissions, which may be offered and may allow you to access the `Uri` for longer.

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for but I am a little unclear on where to implement the persisted permissions. do I need to take the permissions ever time I try to access a uri or just when i am storing the uri?

Comment: @DMcP89: Yeah, the API is a bit goofy here, and I need to play around with this aspect of it more sometime. You definitely call `takePersistableUriPermission()` when you first get the `Uri` (to actually persist the permissions). The docs refer to a problem of the `Uri` being invalid (perfectly reasonable), but I fail to see how calling `takePersistableUriPermission()` addresses that.